# Clicking on a radio button sets tab back to beginning of page on Chrome

Tags: forms, google-chrome, cross-browser, browser

Testing in `Chrome 23.0.1271.64m` on Windows XP and Windows 7.

When tabbing through forms, if you click on a `radio` button, the tab index is reset and the tabbing starts over at the top of the page:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="radio"><!-- click this radio and hit tab -->
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/76FXY/)

IE7-10, Firefox and Opera all continue tabbing from the point of the clicked radio button. What is happening here in Chrome? Is there a trick to make Chrome behave as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little too late, but still.

Having `AutoPostBack` set to `true` for page controls makes you lose focus on any control if it initiates a postback.
You can specify which element has focus in the `Page_Load` or `Page_Init`, but if you don't, that page is loaded without any focus set (also counts for update panels).

To avoid this, make sure you don't apply `AutoPostBack` by default if you don't have too, it'll save you a lot of work in the long run.